# Active Directory Creating An User

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm trying to add an user to the active directory via a C# script. I've found this script on the internet (I didn't made it myself). The problem is that I get this error when I'm trying to add an user:

> The specified directory service attribute or value does not exist.

This is the code I have right now:

```
private void buttonCreateUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CreateADSUser(textboxUsername.Text, textboxPassword.Text);
}

public string CreateADSUser(string username, string password)
{
    String RootDSE;
    try
    {
        DirectorySearcher DSESearcher = new DirectorySearcher();
        RootDSE = DSESearcher.SearchRoot.Path;

        RootDSE = RootDSE.Insert(7, "CN=Users,");

        DirectoryEntry myDE = new DirectoryEntry(RootDSE);
        DirectoryEntries myEntries = myDE.Children;

        DirectoryEntry myDirectoryEntry = myEntries.Add("CN=" + username, "user");
        myDirectoryEntry.Properties["userPrincipalName"].Value = username;
        myDirectoryEntry.Properties["name"].Value = username;
        myDirectoryEntry.Properties["Password"].Value = password;
        myDirectoryEntry.Properties["samAccountName"].Value = username;
        myDirectoryEntry.Properties["FullName"].Value = username;
        myDirectoryEntry.Properties["AccountDisabled"].Value = 0;
        myDirectoryEntry.Properties["PasswordRequired"].Value = 1;

        // Permanent Password?
        myDirectoryEntry.Properties["permpass"].Value = 1;
        myDirectoryEntry.CommitChanges();

        DSESearcher.Dispose();
        myDirectoryEntry.Dispose();

        textboxReports.Text = "Worked!";
        return "Worked!";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        textboxReports.Text = ex.Message;
        return ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: Okay. Won't happen again, I'm not good at making titles :(.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: Might just help me :), thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I've got the fix!

This is what it looks like right now:

```
using (var pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
            {
                using (var up = new UserPrincipal(pc))
                {
                    up.SamAccountName = textboxUsername.Text; // Username
                    up.EmailAddress = textboxEmail.Text; // Email
                    up.SetPassword(textboxPassword.Text); // Password
                    up.Enabled = true;
                    up.ExpirePasswordNow();
                    up.Save();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that none of these properties actually exist:

```
myDirectoryEntry.Properties["Password"].Value = password; 
myDirectoryEntry.Properties["FullName"].Value = username; 
myDirectoryEntry.Properties["AccountDisabled"].Value = 0; 
myDirectoryEntry.Properties["PasswordRequired"].Value = 1; 
myDirectoryEntry.Properties["permpass"].Value = 1;
```

This one isn't one you write to:

```
myDirectoryEntry.Properties["name"].Value = username;
```

In order (from top to bottom) here are the actual attribute names:

- Password - `unicodePwd`
- FullName - `displayName`
- AccountDisabled - `userAccountControl`
- PasswordRequired - `userAccountControl` (actually you set the inverse - only if a password isn't required)
- permPass - `unicodePwd` (not sure what the goal was with this one)

Comment: Ooh, I didn't knew that, thanks! Where can I find the names of the properties btw?

Comment: Start here - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675085(v=vs.85).aspx. Drill down to classes (e.g. user) and then open that page to see the attributes on the specific type of object. You can review info about each attribute from there as well.

Answer (score 0):

By System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement ..

```
              PrincipalContext ouContex = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "TestDomain.local",           "OU=TestOU,DC=TestDomain,DC=local");

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                UserPrincipal up = new UserPrincipal(ouContex);
                up.SamAccountName = "TestUser" + i;
                up.SetPassword("password");
                up.Enabled = true;
                up.ExpirePasswordNow();
                up.Save();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

By System.DirectoryServices

```
To use this namespace you need to add reference  System.DirectoryServices.dll 

       DirectoryEntry ouEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://OU=TestOU,DC=TestDomain,DC=local");

        for (int i = 3; i < 6; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                DirectoryEntry childEntry = ouEntry.Children.Add("CN=TestUser" + i, "user");
                childEntry.CommitChanges();
                ouEntry.CommitChanges();
                childEntry.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { "password" });
                childEntry.CommitChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```